# What does "One sought to be a dentist now is sleeping with the fish" refer to?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, soundtrack, guardians-of-galaxy-holiday-special

In the *[Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13623136/)* the Old 97s sing a parody about Christmas.

One of its lyrics doesn't make sense to me. What does the lyric "One sought to be a dentist now is sleeping with the fish" refer to? All of the lyrics are a "misunderstanding" of a real Christmas tradition or reference, but I can't figure out the original tradition or reference for this lyric.

For some reason I keep thinking it refers to one of the stop-motion Christmas animations I watched as a kid... but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the main characters in the famous [*Rudolph the Red Nosed Reindeer* Christmas special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_(TV_special)) with stop motion animation that first aired December 6, 1964 was Hermey, an Elf who left Santa's workshop because his ambition was to be a dentist.

If someone was writing a parody about Christmas and about beloved Christmas characters, they might think of claiming that Hermey was executed by cruel Santa for trying to leave Santa's workshop, or that he did leave and was killed in the cold cruel outside world.

Comment: "*sleeping with the fishes*" is a sicilian mob message. Means "*dead*".